# Kubernetes kind not able to pull image

Tags: kubernetes

i am using `kind` to setup kubernetes cluster in my local i have loaded `redis:5.0.7` image to kind by using below command 
`kind load docker-image redis:5.0.7 --name kind` for the first time it gave me success 
 now it's not able to pull/load that image while deploying pod. Below is my pod definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis-pod
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  containers:
    - name: redis-ctr
      image: reids:5.0.7
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

i am getting below error

```
Warning  Failed     4s    kubelet, kind-control-plane  Failed to pull image "reids:5.0.7": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/reids:5.0.7": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/reids:5.0.7": pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

when i tried similar steps for my custom image it worked but for redis `insufficient_scope: authorization failed` 
even in [kind documentation](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/known-issues/#unable-to-pull-images) also mentioned that this issue occurs when you don't mention cluster name while loading the image to kind but i have provided name correctly
Can anyone please help me ?

 Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the image you have by mistake placed

```
 reids:5.0.7
```

at place of

```
redis:5.0.7
```

Comment: i just don't know why ppl downvote, I just tried to help the stuck fellow